# Macro to shorten a struct member reference in C

Tags: c

The following fictitious C dialect doesn't work, because a C expression cannot be a macro.

However, there a way to achieve such an abbreviated reference in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{

    int connected;
}connection;

typedef struct{
    connection d[2];
}connections;

#define (c.d[i]) (c.d[i].connected)

main()
{

   connections c;
   if(c.d[x]){
       printf("sos");
   }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered by referring to a programming language reference manual (an off-site resource).

Comment: This is a very poor quality question. "I'm going to invent a fictitious, hypothetical dialect of C. Does it happen to coincide with the real one? Screw reference manuals!"

Comment: @Kaz StackOverflow is often much more useful than a reference manual. It may not a particularly high-quality question, but I don't blame the OP for coming here.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart It turns out there is a valid question in there; it's just badly posed. I edited it and voted to reopen.

Comment: The right solution here is some kind of functional abstraction. Perhaps `if (connected(c, i)) ...` where we have `#define connected(C, I) ((C).d[I].connected)`.

Comment: @Kaz That was my first thought as well, but I'm guessing that this wasn't in line with what the op wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

No. Macro names must be valid C identifiers (alphanumeric characters and underscores, can't start with a number).

Comment: Identifiers may also contain the universal character names listed in C 2011 D.1 and other implementation-defined characters. But that will not help the OP.